# Format of CSV file to upload to GEE

Tags: geopandas, google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload a geometry file in .csv format to GEE.
The file uploads just fine, but when I add layer nothing shows up.

```
    id  type    geometry                                            bbox                                        ID  class   fold
0   0   Feature ((77.550514, 8.086537), (77.550491, 8.086268),...   (77.550491, 8.086245, 77.550784, 8.086537)  1   1   5
1   1   Feature ((77.34729, 9.083161), (77.347313, 9.082892), ...   (77.34729, 9.082892, 77.347584, 9.083185)   10  1   5
2   2   Feature ((79.288295, 11.689556), (79.288318, 11.689287...   (79.288295, 11.689287, 79.288592, 11.68958) 100 1   5
3   3   Feature ((81.296733, 24.542596), (81.296755, 24.542327...   (81.296733, 24.542327, 81.297049, 24.542619)    1000    1   1
4   4   Feature ((76.939523, 11.308145), (76.9395, 11.307876),...   (76.9395, 11.307853, 76.939796, 11.308145)  10000   2   3
```

Please let me know how I can fix it in order to upload this csv file to GEE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the .csv to shapefile, then upload it as an asset to GEE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved it by changing the format of the geometry variable to WKT. So, it looks like this: POLYGON(77.550514 8.086537, 77.550491 8.086268, ..., 77.550514 8.086537). Then the .csv file uploads and displays correctly.